# HTML div tag position

Tags: html

Here's my code I want the form and the iframe section side by side.There should be no gap between.So I set left div tag's width to 30% and right div tag to 70% but its not working.There is gap in between form section and iframe section.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Form and iFrame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div style="float:left; width=30%; background:#f45942">
     <form action="">
     <fieldset > 
     <legend> Sample Form</legend>
     <input type="text" /> <br /> <br />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" /> <br /> <br />
     <input type="email" placeholder="Email or Phone Number" /> <br /> <br />
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password" /> <br /> <br />
     
     <select name="day" id=""> 
      <option value="0">Day</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">1</option>
     </select>
     <select name="month" id=""> 
      <option value="0">Month</option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
     </select>
     <select name="year" id=""> 
      <option value="0">Year</option>
      <option value="1">1992</option>
      <option value="2">1982</option>
     </select> <br /> <br />
     <input type="radio"  id="m" name="gender"/> <label for="m"> Male</label> 
     <input type="radio"  id="f" name="gender"/> <label for="f"> Female</label> <br /> <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" /> <br /> <br />
     <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br />
     <input type="color" /> <br />
     <input type="file" /> <br />
     
     
     </fieldset>
     </form>
     </div>
     
     <div style="float:right; width=70%; background:#f9e000">
      <header>
       <h1>Learn PSD TO HTML</h1>
      </header>
      <div> 
       <h3>Lesson 1</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/czIRtH1n2bQ?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gnow7e45LQFkNVxwQ5BH-W" frameborder="2" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 2</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aikEy1m8z5g" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 3</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jLQqTeWkXzs?rel=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 4</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2ZVdUtbNDiw?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 5</h3>
       <iframe width="320" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CxQoY895iOE?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: change  `width=70%;`  in style attribute to  `width:70%;`  and check,Also `width=30%;` to `width:30%;`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on your `width`s in `<div style="float:right; width=70%; background:#f9e000">` & `<div style="float:left; width:30%; background:#f45942">`

Correct would be `width: 30%;` & `width: 70%;`

So change to:
`<div style="float:right; width:70%; background:#f9e000">`

And:
`<div style="float:left; width:30%; background:#f45942">`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change width=70%; in style attribute to width:70%; and check,Also width=30%; to width:30%;

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Form and iFrame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div style="float:left; width:30%; background:#f45942">
     <form action="">
     <fieldset > 
     <legend> Sample Form</legend>
     <input type="text" /> <br /> <br />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" /> <br /> <br />
     <input type="email" placeholder="Email or Phone Number" /> <br /> <br />
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password" /> <br /> <br />
     
     <select name="day" id=""> 
      <option value="0">Day</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">1</option>
     </select>
     <select name="month" id=""> 
      <option value="0">Month</option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
     </select>
     <select name="year" id=""> 
      <option value="0">Year</option>
      <option value="1">1992</option>
      <option value="2">1982</option>
     </select> <br /> <br />
     <input type="radio"  id="m" name="gender"/> <label for="m"> Male</label> 
     <input type="radio"  id="f" name="gender"/> <label for="f"> Female</label> <br /> <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" /> <br /> <br />
     <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br />
     <input type="color" /> <br />
     <input type="file" /> <br />
     
     
     </fieldset>
     </form>
     </div>
     
     <div style="float:right; width:70%; background:#f9e000">
      <header>
       <h1>Learn PSD TO HTML</h1>
      </header>
      <div> 
       <h3>Lesson 1</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/czIRtH1n2bQ?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gnow7e45LQFkNVxwQ5BH-W" frameborder="2" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 2</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aikEy1m8z5g" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 3</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jLQqTeWkXzs?rel=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 4</h3>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2ZVdUtbNDiw?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       <br />
       <h3>Lesson 5</h3>
       <iframe width="320" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CxQoY895iOE?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given a thought about using BootStrap css for stylling, simply use this to include it in your html

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

now you can use now your page is divided into 12 cols, you can use

```
class="col-md-3"
```

on a div for which you want to give 25% of page width, this will save you a lot of time worrying about setting css properties , you can refer to http://getbootstrap.com/ for more details